# Install .ttf file in client

Tags: java, war, truetype

I have a question about TrueType Fonts and their installation in the client side.
I know they can be installed in the operating system manually. But I have another question.

For my Java web application, it has been designed a new font, formatted in its .ttf file.
I'd like to config the font in my application (.war file), so the client side (any computer with a web navigator like IE, Firefox, etc.) goes to the server, that generates the page (from .jsp files) and the client views it with the font.

I know my question is very abstract. Must the font file be distributed to all the clients? Or is there any other solution which does not involve the final user, by doing something in the server?

Any suggestion is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install the font to the client, but modern browsers can load them as needed. Google provides a number of fonts via their [Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) API. If you want to use custom fonts I'd suggest to look at how they do it.

Basically in HTML you load a CSS like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Tangerine';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Tangerine'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/font?kit=HGfsyCL5WASpHOFnouG-RKCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c') format('truetype');
}
```

The URL points to the TTF file. This makes the font "Tangerine" available in your site. For the full example look at their [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html) document.

Comment: Something to be aware of is font licensing. Do not embed or distribute a font to which you do not have a license to do so! The Google Webfonts that are mentioned here are all be safe to embed.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution for me if I were using a public, normal font, but it's a private font within a corporation. Thank you for your suggestions, they are helpful, because I don't know this css issue.

Comment: You can still use your private font with the methods described above. Just deploy your font with your web application (say in a fonts/ subdirectory). In CSS you specify the URL to point to your deployed font, e.g. `url('fonts/myprivatefont.ttf');`.